# try catch: исключение, если в массиве нет отрицательных чисел

Tags: c#, исключения

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать исключение 
Проверяется массив на наличие в нем отрицательных чисел, как только отрицательное число находится, цикл `while` прекращается.
Помогите написать исключение для ситуации, когда в массиве не окажется отрицательных чисел
кусок из кода

```
    bool count = false;
    int k = 0;
    try
    {
        while (count == false)
        {
            if (mas[k] < 0)
            {
                count = true;
            }
            ++k;
        }
    }

    catch
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

А зачем Вам исключение???

```
bool count = false;
int k;
for (k = 0; k < mas.Length; k++)
{
    if (mas[k] < 0)
    {
        count = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!count)
{
  // ups! no negative
}
```

Но если исключение очень сильно нужно, то это можно организовать

```
bool count = false;
int k = 0;
try
{
    for (k = 0; k < mas.Length; k++)
    {
        if (mas[k] < 0)
        {
            count = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!count)
{
  throw new System.ArgumentException("AnyNegative");
}
catch
{
   // 
}
```

Comment: в первом случае кода, если не будет найдено ни одного отрицательного числа, программа уйдет в бесконечный цикл. я хочу "мягко" завершить программу и вывести сообщение "В массиве не найдено ни одного отрицательного числа".

Comment: Исправил. Да, нетривиальный способ поиска Вы избрали...

Comment: А for? тогда же программа не уйдёт в бесконечный цикл...

Answer (score 1):

```
bool count = false;
int counter = 0;
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < mask.length; i++)
    {
        if (mask[i] < 0)
        {
            counter++
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Error message");
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

Только, зачем так сложно, почему не подходит `If`?

Comment: Человек хочет исключительную ситуацию, если **не найдено** ни одного отрицательного числа.

Comment: Поправил XD

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Linq;

int[] arr = new int[] { 0, 2, 1, -2, -8 };
int neg = (from dig in arr where dig<0).Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один LINQ-вариант:

```
if (mas.All(x => x >= 0))
    throw new ArgumentException("no negative items!");
```

Если вам нужен сам отрицательный элемент, делайте так:

```
var maybeNegative = mas.Where(x => x < 0).Select(x => (int?)x).FirstOrDefault();
if (maybeNegative == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("no negative items!");
var negative = maybeNegative.Value;
```